# Can user defined function change default server collation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, collation

I`m using MSSQL Server 2014 for my web application where database collation is set to Latin1_General_CI_AS. In one of my queries I have problem with Turkish characters. Probably, problem occurs in user defined function which is called from query. So the question is, can collation of columns be changed if I for example alter table but not set any collation (I think that default DB collation should be set by default) change their type?

Comment: Are UDF and query on the same database?

Comment: I don't think so. Try it on a test database.

Comment: @McNets yes, they are on the same database.

Comment: What is exactly the problem, is there any error message?